# show binary data in gridview

Tags: vb.net, pdf, datagridview

Imports System.IO
Public Class frmrequest
#Region "توابع و متد ها"

```
Private Sub LoadList()
    Try

       
       
      
        Dim buttonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        buttonColumn.HeaderText = "View PDF"
        buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
        buttonColumn.DataPropertyName = "peyvast"
        buttonColumn.Name = "peyvast"
        Me.dwgrequest.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
        buttonColumn.Text = "View"
              dwgrequest.Refresh()
        Me.dwgrequest.DataSource = Nothing
        Me.dwgrequest.DataSource = requestMGR.GetrequestDetailList
        Me.dwgrequest.Refresh()
        Me.dwgrequest.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

       
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

#End Region
#Region "روال رویدادها"

```
Private Sub frmrequest_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    ClearGridView()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearGridView()
   
    dwgrequest.DataSource = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub frmrequest_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadList()
End Sub
```

#End Region

```
Private Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
    AddNewrequest()
End Sub

        

Private Sub dwgrequest_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dwgrequest.CellContentClick

    If dwgrequest.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "peyvast" AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If dwgrequest.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("peyvast").Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(dwgrequest.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("peyvast").Value) Then
            Dim binaryData As Byte() = CType(dwgrequest.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("peyvast").Value, Byte())

            Dim tempFilePath As String = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".pdf"
            File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, binaryData)

                          Process.Start(tempFilePath)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dwgrequest_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dwgrequest.CellFormatting
    If dwgrequest.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "peyvast" Then ' Replace YourBinaryColumnIndex with the index of the binary column in the DataGridView
        If e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(e.Value) Then
            Dim button As New Button()
            button.Text = "View PDF"
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf ViewPDFButton_Click
            e.Value = button
        Else
            e.Value = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ViewPDFButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow = dwgrequest.CurrentRow
    If selectedRow IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim binaryData As Byte() = CType(selectedRow.Cells("peyvast").Value, Byte()) ' Replace YourBinaryColumnIndex with the index of the binary column in the DataGridView
       
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class
I want the "Peyvast" column in the datagrid to read the binary value from the database and by pressing the button, the PDF file will be displayed, but unfortunately, the value of the fields in this column stores the word view as value.

According to the performed tests, the value read from the database is correct, but the value of pywast column changes during execution